# How can I search for a certain method in android profiler?

Tags: android, methods, profiling, profiler, ddms

I get thousands of methods and I can´t locate the one I was looking for.

There is a "find" text field above, which seems to don´t have any effect

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you are right, the find wont work..
But if you know the method name and package name you can sort the list and search for your method..